# How to achieve conditional compilation in one project depending on symbols in another project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, conditional-compilation

Suppose a Visual Studio project `ProjectA.SampleClass` that has a method wrapped inside `#if DEBUG ... #endif` symbols, i.e. the method will only be included in Debug builds:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    ...
    #if DEBUG
    public void ConditionalMethod() { ... }
    #endif
}
```

Another project, `ProjectB`, calls `SampleClass.ConditionalMethod()`, but obviously it can only do successfully if ProjectA defines a DEBUG constant.

Is there a built-in way to check in `ProjectB`, at compile time, if `ProjectA` has the DEBUG constant defined? Something like this:

```
#if ProjectA.DEBUG
ProjectA.SampleClass.ConditionalMethod();
#endif
```

I can think of some obscure AOP ways to achieve something like this with post-compilation IL editing, but that's not very desirable.

Answer (score 0):

Try with new build configuration configuration. Go to solution right click and select Configuration Manager. From here define new configuration. After that make sure that you new configuration is selected and you will see how the column Configuration for each project is set to the new configuration. If not - select it. Then define the symbols that you want for each project.

Answer (score 0):

A better design would probably be to define the method either way, and have one of the methods simply be a no-op:

```
#if DEBUG
public void ConditionalMethod() { ... }
#else
public void ConditionalMethod() {} // Method does nothing
#endif
```

(You could also simply place the #if/#endif around the body of the method, of course.)

Then Project B can call the method regardless, with its behavior changing depending on how Project A was compiled.

Comment: Sure, I know that - thanks anyway. I was just curious if there's some functionality that I'm missing, because in my actual case (the question is just a sample as it's easier to demonstrate), I have entire classes that are debug-only.

Comment: There isn't any direct method as far as I know.

I'm not even sure what the runtime would do if an assembly contains a call to a class in another assembly that doesn't exist, even if that code path never executes...

It could be done using Reflection. You would have to try to get the type (from Assembly.GetTypes), then check for the presence of the method, then if it exists use the MethodInfo to execute the method. That sounds like more trouble than it's probably worth, though; using something like Dependency Injection might be a more worthwhile endeavor.

Comment: Agreed. Perhaps an AOP library ala PostSharp could be of help, but I'm merely guessing. If I wanted to go all the way I'd probably write my own tool that would parse the generated IL and take out the marked parts of code; i.e. the inverse to injecting e.g. logging/tracing aspects into methods as a post-compilation step. This would have zero run-time overhead, but would resemble a Rube Goldberg device a bit too much at this point to be worth the effort for me.